Azure Devops Pipeline: each in iteration in sequence
The following pipeline, with a each .. in .. iteration, the jobs will run in parallel.
variables:
  - name: fruitList
    value: mango,peach
stages:
  - stage: Dev
    jobs:
      - ${{ each fruitName in split(parameters.fruitList, ',') }}:
          - job: "HELLO_${{ fruitName }}"
            steps:
              - task: AzureCLI@2
                displayName: "Step dynamic ${{ fruitName }}"
                inputs:
                  scriptType: "bash"
                  scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
                  inlineScript: |
                    set -xe    
                    set -o nounset    
                    echo "${{ fruitName }}"

How can I make the jobs run in Sequence, or even better, set a batchCount to control the maximum number of parallel jobs.

By default jobs run in parallel but stages run sequentially - if you generate a stage for each fruit these will run in sequence.

You can use the matrix strategy to limit the maximum number of jobs running in parallel.
Example pipeline:
parameters:
  - name: fruitList
    type: string
    displayName: 'A comma separated list of fruits'
    default: 'mango,peach,apple,banana'

  - name: maxParallel
    type: number
    displayName: 'Maximum number of jobs running in parallel'
    default: 2

trigger: none

stages:
  - stage: Dev
    jobs:
      - job: Hello
        strategy:
          maxParallel: ${{ parameters.maxParallel }}
          matrix:
            ${{ each fruit in split(parameters.fruitList, ',') }}:
              ${{ fruit }}: # job name will be 'Hello {{ fruit }}'
                fruitName: ${{ fruit }} # use $(fruitName) to access the value
                foo: bar # additional variables can be set here
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: |
              echo "Fruit name: $(fruitName)"

Running the pipeline:

Notes:

Jobs run in parallel but order is not guaranteed. When I first ran the pipeline, first job to be executed was Hello peach
Matrix configuration names must contain only basic Latin alphabet letters (A-Z and a-z), digits (0-9), and underscores (_). They must start with a letter. Also, their length must be 100 characters or fewer.


To control the maximum number of parallel jobs, you can use the matrix strategy as mentioned by @Rui Jarimba.
To control the order of jobs, you can use job dependency. But you will not be able to run in parallel. Use an object to pass fruitname and job dependency. See the example below.
parameters:
- name: FruitList
  type: object
  default:
  - FruitName: mango
    Dependency: []
  - FruitName: peach
    Dependency: HELLO_mango
  - FruitName: apple
    Dependency: HELLO_peach

stages:
- stage: Dev
  jobs:
  - ${{ each Fruit in parameters.FruitList }}:
    - job: "HELLO_${{ Fruit.FruitName }}"
      dependsOn: ${{ Fruit.Dependency }}
      steps:
      - script: echo ${{ Fruit.FruitName }}


thanks. but the input is a comma separated string that the pipeline does not control
